# Can't get profile data in Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, profile, httpcontext, application-start

I have the following code at some point in Application_Start

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

foreach (MembershipUser u in users)
{
    ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(u.UserName, false);

    if (profile["Index"] != null)
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i try to access the profile properties I get "Request is not available in this context" httpException. I have tried using profile.GetPropertyValue but no luck also.

Why does profile need the request object and how can I get this to work?

**EDIT:**

I have looked into the .NET code and found that at some point `SqlProfileProvider.GetPropertyValuesFromDatabase(string userName, SettingsPropertyValueCollection svc)` is called, inside of which rests this string of code:

```
if (!current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
```

Apparently this will never work if not in request context. The workaround descripbed in Onur's answer will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to access request object which is not possible in your case.

Please take a look following link and apply one of workarounds if possible.
http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart

and if you give more information what are you trying to achieve we can find another way.

Comment: I already read about the integrated mode. The problem seems to be in the BaseProfile, which tries to access the request object, on property access. I try to aggregate the Index property of all profiles, on app startup. But before I make the workarounds in that post, I would like to be sure that i'm not missing something.

Comment: Why do you the request object particularly in this case? If you don t need it make a null control(or try block) and continue your process.

Comment: I don't use the Request object, I need to get property value from the profile, which throws the exception when i try to.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the "string value" properties by querying the aspnet_Profiles table and parsing the string.

```
SELECT [UserName]
  ,[PropertyNames]
  ,[PropertyValuesString]
FROM [aspnet_Profile]
LEFT JOIN [aspnet_Users] on [aspnet_Users].UserId = [aspnet_Profile].UserId
```

The PropertyValuesString can be parsed with a bit of code. This link should explain the format in detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478953.aspx#persistence_format.